# How to handle authentication for a oauth2 authorization server

Tags: authentication, go, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have an oauth2 auth endpoint (x), this endpoint is behind an authentication (y)(browser auth username password) and then (z)(browser auth username password) then it redirects to a new redirection endpoint mentioned on the oauth2 auth endpoint to suffix the authorization code for a grant.

once the y and z have happened in the browser it is cached in the session for the next oauth2 auth endpoint it redirects directly to the oauth2 redirect URL with code.

now the question is how do we achieve this in a non-interactive session, say I want to use that code and generate an oauth2 access token, but I want to create the authorization code grant itself at the code level.

I'm looking for a way to automotive this in Golang using golang.org/x/oauth2 package. any suggestions how this can be achieved

Comment: Only the oauth2 server can generate authorization codes. Otherwise oauth2 wouldn't be worth anything.

Comment: yeah, but the oauth2 auth endpoint is under a authentication hood

Comment: Oauth2 has several kinds of token `grant_type` that change de mechanism of login, so the automation will depends of how you log in on your web platform. What `grant_type` is used for the `/token` endpoint? `authorization_code`? `password`?

Comment: ```authorization_code```

Comment: problem is, to generate an authorization code, we need to complete to login challenge by calling the authorization endpoint with response_type, grant type, login verifier, challenge method, client id, etc but this auth endpoint is behind an authentication server that requires a POST API with username and password to another endpoint